# Sitecom X3 N300 router: is possible to access to telnet to change the port management?

Tags: router, telnet

I have the router in subject (Sitecom X3 N300).
I need to open the port 80 for an internal server but doing this I lost possibility to external management (and I need also to login to the router some time).

I did try to move the 81 vs 80 in virtual server to access from external from EXTERNAL_IP:81 but it doesn't work.

So, I'm tryng to login to telnet, but I cannot do for username or password wrong.

I did try standard admin/admin etc without success. Of course I did try also with my custom password.

Anyone know OR how to change the port or access to telnet? (in worst scenario, I could also administer the router from telnet outside my LAN).

Thank you very much